# EntityManager is null evenAfter added the springDataJpa dependency

Tags: java, configuration, null, javabeans, entitymanager

I'm trying to create the Hibernate's SessionFactory bean from JPA's EntityManager with the following lines But am getting EntityManger is null.I don't want to extend the JPARepository.Hences creating bean for SessionFactory in configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        if (entityManager == null) {
            logger.info("EntityManager is null---");
        } else {
            if (entityManager.unwrap(Session.class) == null) {

                return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getSessionFactory();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Logger Info printed in console:**
EntityManager is null---

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
     <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
             <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>        
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `@EnableJpaRepositories` Autowiring of EntityManager is a feature that is provided by Spring Data JPA module. It is not provided by usual Spring JPA integration.

Or you can use `@PersistenceContext` to inject an `EntityManager` without using Spring Data JPA. This is shown in the Spring Framework reference documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#dao-annotations

Answer (score 0):

Got solution for my Issue:
After debugging internal Springboot code, Am able to get the entityManager instance inside the repository class.

EntityManager instance is null in configuration Class,However EntityManager is not null in Repository class.